# Factoring an arbitary variable in mathematica

Tags: polynomials

Imagine we have a equation like this

```
 gf= 1 + (a3 - a1 x)^2 w1 + (b3 - b2 x)^2 w2
```

how can I reach the following equation

```
 gf2= 1 + a1^2 k1^2  xw1 + (b3 - b2 x)^2 xw2
```

where

```
k1 = -(a3/a1 - x)
```

is it possible to use something like this

```
1 + (a3 - a1 x)^2 w1 + (b3 - b2 x)^2 w2/.-(a3/a1 - x)->k1
```

actually I tried and didn't work
Thanks

Comment: `PolynomialQuotient`

Comment: It did not work, could you please explain more?

Comment: can you provide an expected output?

Comment: Let me tell you more simple example imagin a1 x1 + a2 y1 + b3 b4 x1 + a2 x1=function then for this function I want to factor a1 x1/a2 the I will get a1 x1/a2( a2 +a2^2 y1/(x1 a1)+... something like this

Comment: why not use `Expand[f/f1]`? it gives you the expected output.

Comment: amin,  you should react to the comments to make the most of your and other people's effort.

Comment: @Yves Klett , ok, I will do that from now on, but still the problem has not been solved:(

Comment: what about the suggestions from @happyfish?

Comment: @aminbk Did I misunderstand some part?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. using Expand[f/f1] does not work, in this example. Because the equation is complicated and cumbersome, also all terms are not next to each other, I mean (a1x1y1 +b1 y/z +1/z^2y1^1/2) then you want to factor two things let say one is (a1/z) and lets say y^3 , this case I have some problem with Expand

Comment: Crossposted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/849687

Answer (score 2):

```
FullSimplify[Eliminate[{gf == 1 + (a3 - a1 x)^2 w1 + (b3 - b2 x)^2 w2, 
   k1 == -(a3/a1 - x)}, {a3}], Assumptions -> a1 != 0]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]